# ASP.NET MVC as a desktop thick client application. Is it possible?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, desktop-application

I'm just curios whether such possibility exists.

Here what I mean:

Suppose I have an ASP.NET MVC site. And some classical .exe application which stores this site as a resource.
When user starts this application, server runs in the context of the process (without any outside exposure) and processes the requests from the same process. At the same time client sees generated content in a browser-like window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need

1. **IIS Hostable Web Core** to host website
   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2008/04/14/hostyourownwebserverusingiis7.aspx
2. **WebBrowser Control** to access site from your windows app
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx 
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752041(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You mean without tcp involved? I'm not sure, you'll have to read hostable web core documentation.